# Access app.logger in submodule in Flask application

Tags: python, flask

I am following the official [flask tutorial](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.2.x/tutorial/).
I have already set up blueprints and they are working just fine.

I can use `app.logger.debug('route "/hello" called')` from `__init__.py` to log something–my issue is that I am struggling to use the `app.logger` from `routes/routes.py` though...

I have set up a structure like this:

```
fzwk_access
├── __init__.py
├── db.py
├── routes
│   ├── routes.py
│   ├── ...
...
```

So here's the question:

how can I use the `app.logger` from the file `routes.py`?

I already tried the following:

- use `from flask import app` which did not work
- use `from fzwk_access import __init__` which does not work as I don't have `app` as a global variable there (I guess?)

My `__init__.py` looks like this:

```py
import os

from flask import Flask

def create_app(test_config=None):
    # create and configure the app
    app = Flask(__name__, instance_relative_config=True)
    app.config.from_mapping(
        SECRET_KEY='dev',
        DATABASE=os.path.join(app.instance_path, 'flaskr.sqlite'),
    )

    if test_config is None:
        # load the instance config, if it exists, when not testing
        app.config.from_pyfile('config.py', silent=True)
    else:
        # load the test config if passed in
        app.config.from_mapping(test_config)

    # ensure the instance folder exists
    try:
        os.makedirs(app.instance_path)
    except OSError:
        pass

    # a simple page that says hello
    @app.route('/hello')
    def hello():
        app.logger.debug('route "/hello" called')
        return 'Hello, World!'

    from . import db
    db.init_app(app)

    from .routes import routes, routes_admin, routes_logs
    app.register_blueprint(routes.home_bp)
    app.register_blueprint(routes_admin.admin_bp)
    # app.register_blueprint(routes_logs.logs_bp)

    return app
```

Comment: have you tried `from flask import current_app as app` because this proxy should always point to current instance of the app

Comment: Nope, I have not... Believe it or not–I have not found a single mention of this which shows (at least...) two things: my google-foo was failing me _and_ I probably have not studied the documentation carefully enough... I can confirm that this works–if you want to translate this into a quick answer I will accept asap. Thanks!